# Cannot find module '@/assets/icons/pay/pay-success.png' or its corresponding type declarations.ts

Tags: typescript, vite

when I tried to import the png image in typescript using this code:

```
import paySuccessIcon from "@/assets/icons/pay/pay-success.png";
```

the visual studio code show error:

```
Cannot find module '@/assets/icons/pay/pay-success.png' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)
No quick fixes available
```

I am sure the png file exists and the path is correct. why did the happen? what should I do to avoid this issue? this is the `vite.config.ts`:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import path from 'node:path';
import dts from 'vite-plugin-dts';
import { resolve } from 'path';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        react({
            
        }),
        dts({
            insertTypesEntry: true,
        })
    ],
    build: {
        lib: {
            entry: resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.ts'),
            name: 'rd-component',
            formats: ['es'],
            fileName: (format) => `rd-component.${format}.js`
        },
        assetsDir: 'src/assets',
        sourcemap: true,
        rollupOptions: {
            external: ['react', 'react-dom', 'styled-components'],
            output: {
                globals: {
                    react: 'React',
                    'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
                    'styled-components': 'styled',
                },
            },
        },
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have @rollup/plugin-alias installed in your project ?

If yes, maybe try to change `path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')` to  `path.resolve(__dirname, './src')`.

If this doesn't work, I'm out of options sorry :)